# Existence nontrivial Killing vector field $\iff$ existence nontrivial $\Bbb S^1$-action

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, group-actions

Where can I find proof of the following classical fact?

> The existence of a nontrivial Killing vector field on a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ is equivalent to the existence of a nontrivial
>   $\Bbb S^1$-action on $M$.

Is there any counterexample in non-compact case?

Comment: For the second question, consider the manifold $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric has a killing vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, but $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial continuous $S^{1}$-actions. To see this, note that any non-trivial orbit of an $S^{1}$-action is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$, but no subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$. The first question is very interesting and I hope it gets answered!

Comment: @NickL: In the non-compact case is it true still existence of a nontrivial S1-action = existence a Killing?

Comment: It is true that existence of an isometric $S^1$-action $\implies$ the existence of a killing vector field, for non-compact manifolds. The proof is that "differentiating the circle action" gives a killing vector field, I can give more details if you want. The coverse is false for $\mathbb{R}$ as shown above,

Comment: @NickL: I like to see that and obstruction to its converse if you know.

Comment: It is my above comment. The vector field  $d/dx$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is killing for the standard metric. There are not $S^1$-actions on $\mathbb{R}$ (other than the trivial one).

Comment: @NickL: Do you know that my post is equivalent to this: **"integral curves of Killing vector fields are circular"**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The group $\text{Isom}(M)$ has the form of a Lie group; if $M$ is compact, this Lie group is compact.

Given any non-trivial Killing vector field, this gives a map $X: \Bbb R \to \text{Isom}(M)$; its image is a commutative subgroup. The closure of the image of $X$ is still commutative (the equation $ab = ba$ is true on an open dense subset of $\bar X \times \bar X$) and still a subgroup. If $M$ is compact, this subgroup must then be compact; because $\bar X$ is a compact, connected, non-trivial abelian Lie group we thus have $\bar X \cong T^n$ for some $n>0$. In particular, there is a circle subgroup of $\text{Isom}(M)$, and hence a faithful action of $S^1$ on $M$ by isometries.

Comment: That first sentence is non-trivial enough to be named after Myers and Steenrod ;-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem

Comment: @C.F.G:  Sorry, I don't.