# Non-trivial $\Bbb T^k$ action and generalized Killing vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3039600/272127) I know that

> The existence of a nontrivial Killing vector field $\xi$ on a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ is equivalent to the existence of a nontrivial
>   $\Bbb S^1$-action on $M$.

where $\xi$ is called Killing if $\mathcal{L}_\xi g=0$. There is a generalization of Killing vector fields as follows:

> **Definition:** A vector field $\xi$ is called $2$-Killing if $\mathcal{L}_\xi\mathcal{L}_\xi g=0$.

**Question:** What is the relation between "*existence of a nontrivial $2$-Killing vector field on a compact Riemannian manifold*" and "existence of a nontrivial
$\Bbb T^k$-action"?

I know that if $\xi$ is Killing then it is $2$-Killing. So $\Bbb S^1\subset $ isometries generated by $2$-Killing vector fields?

Comment: This relationship seems the wrong way round - 2-Killing is a *weaker* condition than Killing, but a $\mathbb T^2$ action is stronger than an $\mathbb S^1$ action.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think 2-Killing fields generate any kind of isometric action; rather than keeping geometry fixed, their flow instead should change the geometry in some "monotone" way. An isometric $\mathbb T^k$ action just corresponds to the existence of $k$ independent Killing fields. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?